# File uploading with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am currently creating an app using nodejs and reactjs and so far I have created user authentication. Now that the user is authenticated, I want them to be able to upload any type of file, view em and delete them. However, I am unsure of how to successfully complete this goal. Can anyone recommend any resources that can assist me?

Comment: take a look at: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer library. it is effective library for upload files. I have an example in my github account. If you want, you look at https://github.com/serhatleventyavas/nodejs-multer-example

Comment: thank you for this. I can successfully make a Post request with multer this way. Do you know of any resources that can explain using the other CRUD methods with multer, such as Reading, Updating and Deleting?